# Sql Loop - Other than that

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I've read the threads about loops (pros & cons) in and around a SQL statements. I need to "Loop" through 12 hours, hr by hr and was wondering if there is a better way than "Do-While-Loop, etc.) Here is my SQL...

```
SELECT R.FinalProd
, MIN(r.seqnumber) Seq
, MIN(S.RollRecID) RID
, COUNT(DISTINCT S.RollRecID) Pieces
, (MIN(r.seqnumber) + COUNT(DISTINCT S.RollRecID) - 1) endd
FROM NYS1Reheat1 R INNER JOIN NYS1SawPieces S ON R.RecordID = S.RollRecID INNER JOIN TensileProducts T ON R.FinalProd = T.SQLProduct
where s.ShiftIdent = '05/22/15154D' and r.Location = 'HISTORY'
and datepart(hour,s.prodtime) > 17 and datepart(hour,s.prodtime) < 19
GROUP BY R.FinalProd, T.FootWeight
order by RID
```

I need to start at 1700 and go hr by hr to 0600.
My plan, as of now, is to "loop" 12 times through the code.

Thanks,
Doug

Comment: There's a concept called recursive Common Table Expression, `With` keyword, that can do the looping for you.

Comment: A windowing function (look for the PARTITION BY clause) and an additional join can also do what you need

Comment: It seems that I may have not  asked the complete question. I'm returning the min (start #) and max (end #) only for each hour. Actually, doing the math by counting the s.RollRecId pieces to get the max. An example of the full return would be like:

Comment: Sorry bout that, hit return...  HP12X74  52  567456  20  71  -  5 columns.

Comment: You could use a tally or numbers table for this kind of thing instead of looping. Here is one article about the topic. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/

Answer (score 0):

You can cross join your time intervals:

```
;with loop12 as (
   select 17 as f, 19 as t union all
   select 19 as f, 21 as t union all
   ...
)
SELECT R.FinalProd
, MIN(r.seqnumber) Seq
, MIN(S.RollRecID) RID
, COUNT(DISTINCT S.RollRecID) Pieces
, (MIN(r.seqnumber) + COUNT(DISTINCT S.RollRecID) - 1) endd
, loop12.f 
FROM NYS1Reheat1 R 
INNER JOIN NYS1SawPieces S ON R.RecordID = S.RollRecID
INNER JOIN TensileProducts T ON R.FinalProd = T.SQLProduct
CROSS JOIN loop12
WHERE s.ShiftIdent = '05/22/15154D' and r.Location = 'HISTORY'
and datepart(hour,s.prodtime) > loop12.f and datepart(hour,s.prodtime) < loop12.t
GROUP BY R.FinalProd, T.FootWeight
order by RID, loop12.f
```